# Calling a method/function from the code behind of a page im about to redirecting to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect

I'm redirecting to a page like so:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Once this page loads up, and only if it loads from a redirect I want to enable a Panel.

What options do I have to do this?

Comment: you are talking about enable so why you did not think about a boolean type flag or variable?? true(enable), false(disable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What options do I have to do this?

Simplest would be to pass a parameter in `QueryString`  and later in `Default.aspx`'s page load check for that query string, if it is present enable the panel.

For sending:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?enablePanel=true");
```

For checking if the parameter exists.

```
string enablePanel = Request.QueryString["enablePanel"];
if (enablePanel != null && enablePanel == "true") //or parse to bool
{
   //enable panel
}
```

Comment: `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Transferred=true"); //for first page
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Transferred"]) { Boolean showpanel=Boolean.Parse(Request.QueryString["Transferred"]); if (showpanel) {ShowPanel();} }`